# “rename” filter didn’t rename the field in events

Tags: logstash-configuration, elasticsearch-2.0

I used the filter plugin "rename" to rename a field in my events. Logstash didn't show any error on restart. But there doesn't seem to be any changes to the field name(checked in sense plugin). I added "rename" after indexing the file. How can I rename a field after indexing? I'm using LS-2.0, ES-2.0. This is a piece of my logstash.conf file:

```
filter {
    grok {
            match => {"message" => "^(?<EventTime>[0-9 \-\:]*)\s(?<MovieName>[\w.\-\']*)\s(?<Rating>[\d.]+)\s(?<NoOfDownloads>\d+)\s(?<NoOfViews>\d+)" }
        }

    mutate {
        convert => {"Rating" => "float"}
        }
    mutate {
        convert => {"NoOfDownloads" => "integer"}
        }
    mutate {
        convert => {"NoOfViews" => "integer"}
        }

    mutate{
        rename => { "NoOfViews" => "TotalViews" }
        }
>     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either reindex or create elastic search alias for the already indexed data. Direct renaming of the field is not possible on indexed data.